# How can I parse my Mariadb logs that are formatted as a table so it is readable by elasticsearch (JSON)?

Tags: json, regex, logging, elasticsearch, mariadb

I'm attempting to parse the MariaDB general log into a JSON object that can then be interpreted by ElasticSearch. The issue I'm facing is the file MariaDB outputted is structured in this way:

```
   150826 22:17:44 2 Connect   debian-sys-maint@localhost as anonymous 
                   2 Quit
                   3 Connect   debian-sys-maint@localhost as anonymous 
                   3 Quit
   150826 22:18:44 2 Connect   debian-sys-maint@localhost as anonymous 
                   2 Quit
```

I've done the regex to match the first line, with the following:

```
^(?<date>\d{6})\s(?<time>\w{2}:\w{2}:\w{2})\s{5}(?<id>\d*)\s(?<command>\w*)\s{3}(?<argument>.*)
```

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/dU5nA9/1)

Unfortunately I'm not certain how target the other items that occur in that same timeframe, and ideally I would want to ensure those subsequent lines are listed under their respective timeframes. As far as I know this was the only format I could get out of MariaDB, if you know how to make it so the logs are more conventionally formatted that may be even better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe another solution would be to configure MariaDB to [write logs into a table](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/writing-logs-into-tables/). If you configure this then your general log will go into the [`general_log`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/mysqlgeneral_log-table/) table which is already structured (by definition) and you don't need to parse anything.

Then instead of retrieving the raw log file and parse it, you'd retrieve records from that table using the [logstash jdbc input plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-jdbc.html). You'll need to download the MariaDB JDBC connector [here](https://downloads.mariadb.org/connector-java/1.2.0/). Your logstash configuration would go like this:

```
input {
  jdbc {
    jdbc_driver_library => "/path/to/mariadb-connector-java-1.2.0-bin.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver"
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/mydb"
    jdbc_user => "myuser"
    schedule => "1m"
    statement => "SELECT * FROM mysql.general_log WHERE event_time > :sql_last_start"
  }
}
filter {
   ... your filters...
}
output {
    elasticsearch {
        .... your ES config ....
    }
}
```

Comment: Apologies for the lateness, I was on vacation. I went with your initial suggestion, I was under the impression I was bound with formatting using fluentd but that's apparently not the case. Dumping the table to general_log without parsing worked just fine, thanks!